# setvalue.AddOnsucces fail causes ondatachange

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I'm making an app and I have problems with the following listener:

```
RootRef.setValue (...). AddOnSuccessListener
```

The problem is that this listener activates the following:

```
RootRef.addValueEventListener (...)
```

When it does not enter into the addOnSuccessListener and I do not want this to happen to me. Thank you

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas? I do not understand how you can trigger the event that there has been a change in the Firebase database if you do not then type anything

Comment: Thanks for nothing